# MirthConnect Error Database Write Successful but no data found in SQL Server database

Tags: mirth

I have a channel in Mirthconnect which read HL7 messages and then extract relevant information and write to SQL server database. It is showing some unusual behaviour, on the Mirthconnect Message log it shows "SUCCESS: Database write success" but no data found in the database. It works fine and writes data most of the time but sometimes it does this. Normally if there is an error writing data (executing the Javascript) it shows error details in Mirthconnect and I understand that but how come it is showing "Write success" and then no data in the database.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Anyone experienced this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me. 
The solution to it lies with the user that access the database from Mirth. Grant sysadmin server role and public to that user.
Login to the database(SSMS).

Go to Security->login->select your user->right-click properties->server roles. set it as public and sysadmin both.

click OK. And then restart the `MSSQLSERVER` service from SQL Server Configuration Manager. This is required otherwise the changes will not take effect.

Comment: Any more current update to this? Escalating perms to sysadmin is going to make my DBAs and InfoSec people sweat...